# How can I make my function operating on lines interactive instead of waiting for the full input at once?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, read-eval-print-loop

My interepreter supports the following operations:

- `up` (increment the `y` coordinate),
- `down` (decrement the `y` cooridinate),
- `left` (decrement the `x` cooridinate),
- `right` (increment the `x` coordinate),
- `printX` (print the `x` coordinate),
- `printY` (print the `y` coordinate).

My current implementation looks like this

```
interpreterHelper :: [String] -> Int -> Int -> Int -> [String] -> [String]
interpreterHelper cmds index x y output
  | index == length (cmds) = reverse output
  | (cmds !! index) == "up"     = interpreterHelper cmds (index + 1) x (y + 1) output
  | (cmds !! index) == "down"   = interpreterHelper cmds (index + 1) x (y - 1) output
  | (cmds !! index) == "left"   = interpreterHelper cmds (index + 1) (x - 1) y output
  | (cmds !! index) == "right"  = interpreterHelper cmds (index + 1) (x + 1) y output
  | (cmds !! index) == "printX" = interpreterHelper cmds (index + 1) x y (show x : output)
  | (cmds !! index) == "printY" = interpreterHelper cmds (index + 1) x y (show y : output) 

interpreter :: [String] -> [String]
interpreter cmds = interpreterHelper cmds 0 0 0 []
```

However, my exercise requires that I can make it interactive with the following statement:

```
interact (unlines . interpreter . lines)
```

which does not seem to happen.

How can I make it interactive, so that when I, say, type in `printY`, I immediately receive the output of the current value of the `y` - coordinate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious problem is that you collect all output into an accumulator first and only produce anything at the very end, so the code doesn't produce any output until the end.

You can instead produce the output as you go:

```hs
interpreterHelper :: [String] -> Int -> Int -> Int -> [String]
interpreterHelper cmds index x y
  | (cmds !! index) == "up"     = interpreterHelper cmds (index + 1) x (y + 1)
  | (cmds !! index) == "down"   = interpreterHelper cmds (index + 1) x (y - 1)
  | (cmds !! index) == "left"   = interpreterHelper cmds (index + 1) (x - 1) y
  | (cmds !! index) == "right"  = interpreterHelper cmds (index + 1) (x + 1) y
  | (cmds !! index) == "printX" = show x : interpreterHelper cmds (index + 1) x y
  | (cmds !! index) == "printY" = show y : interpreterHelper cmds (index + 1) x y

interpreter :: [String] -> [String]
interpreter cmds = interpreterHelper cmds 0 0 0
```

That does solve the immediate problem of interactiveness.
But it eventually produces an error when we reach the end of the input (we can't use `length` because that would require all elements to be there again). And it's still fairly inefficient. Indexing into a list is often a habit of programmers coming from a non functional background, but for linked lists like Haskell's lists it's complexity is `O(index)` so your function is currently `O(n²)`. You can improve that and in the process get rid of `index` by just matching on the `cmds` list:

```hs
interpreterHelper :: [String] -> Int -> Int -> [String]
interpreterHelper [] _ _ = []
interpreterHelper ("up" : cmds) x y = interpreterHelper cmds x (y + 1)
interpreterHelper ("printY" : cmds) x y = show y : interpreterHelper cmds x y
-- other commands accordingly

interpreter :: [String] -> [String]
interpreter cmds = interpreterHelper cmds 0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

cafce25's answer is a good one for a beginner learning to do things by hand. But I wanted to show another approach for a more experienced Haskeller. Managing lists manually, by deconstructing and reconstructing them recursively, is a bit gauche. Instead, look for a more general idea that your recursive function is a special case of.

In this case, you're doing something that's essentially a fold: you have a coordinate pair, and you're updating it as you work through a list of commands. But the twist is that you sometimes have this additional effect, where instead of updating the coordinate you write a message. "Effect" should scream "monad", and since our effect is to write a message, the monad we should reach for is Writer. And we lift our fold into the Writer type by using `foldM`:

```
import Control.Monad (foldM)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Writer (Writer, execWriter, tell)

interpreter :: [String] -> [String]
interpreter = execWriter . foldM go (0, 0)
  where go c@(x, y) cmd = case cmd of
          "up" -> pure (x, y + 1)
          "down" -> pure (x, y - 1)
          "left" -> pure (x - 1, y)
          "right" -> pure (x + 1, y)
          "printX" -> c <$ yield x
          "printY" -> c <$ yield y
        yield r = tell [show r]
```

It's just as lazy as the other approach, but the recursion and the list handling are all implicit now, and we only have to deal with the "business logic" of deciding whether to update a coordinate or print something.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, let me take the approach suggested by @amalloy, i.e. using monads to model effects, following it as much as possible.

In the solution by @amalloy, we find that output are handled through the `Writer` monad, but the state (the `(x,y)` position value) is still passed around manually.

One can instead use a monad that handles both the mutable `(x,y)` position state, and the generation of new outputs. One such monad is `RWS r w s`: this provides a read-only access to `r` (we don't need that so let's choose `r~()`), a write/append-only access to `w` (we use that for outputs, so we pick `w ~ [String]`), and a read-write access to `s` (the position, so we pick `s ~ (Int, Int)`).

The resulting code is this:

```
import Control.Arrow (first, second)
import Control.Monad.RWS
import Data.Foldable

interpreter :: [String] -> [String]
interpreter = snd . ($ (0, 0)) . ($ ()) . evalRWS . traverse_ go
  where
  go :: String -> RWS () [String] (Int, Int) ()
  -- increment the second component of the state
  go "up"     = modify' (second succ)
  -- decrement the second component of the state
  go "down"   = modify' (second pred)
  -- decrement the first component of the state
  go "left"   = modify' (first  pred)
  -- increment the first component of the state
  go "right"  = modify' (first  succ)
  -- get the first component of the state, and add it to the outputs
  go "printX" = do x <- gets fst; tell [show x]
  -- get the second component of the state, and add it to the outputs
  go "printY" = do y <- gets snd; tell [show y]
  -- for invalid commands, output an error message
  go _        = tell ["invalid command"]
```

I want to remark that this is an advanced solution, and I do not recommend Haskell beginners to use this approach when they are still unfamiliar with the basics of Haskell.

Further, even if I do find this approach to be interesting, for this specific task this solution is not really better than the others, in my eye. I would use this only for more complex tasks, where threading the state and the outputs around starts becoming tedious and error-prone.